# Show only preview RaveReport

Tags: delphi, default, preview, rave-reports

I make a report in Delphi 2010, with Rave Report. My code is this:

```
procedure TMain.ViewReportePrint(Sender: TObject);
var
  report: TBaseReport;
begin
  report := Sender as TBaseReport;
  With report do
  begin

    SetFont('Arial', 15);
    GotoXY(1,1);
    Print('Welcome to Code Based Reporting in Rave');
  end;
end;
```

This works, but, shows window where the user select if, print report, preview and save to file. 
I like, that this window not shows, and show directly the preview report.
How can do this ?.
Thanks !.

Answer (score 0):

In the TrvSystem component, turn off ssAllowSetup in SystemSetups property.  ie, set its value to False.